# How do I open a link in Safari from a native app in iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, web-applications, native

## How do I open a link in Safari from a native app in iPad?

I have a setup like so:

- I have a html/css application
- The app is packaged as native .ipa through Xcode (Cordova etc, it's working and all)

I want it so that when I click a link on the app (a normal a-tag with a href attribute), iPad would open the link in **Safari** and **NOT in the app itself**.

Now it creates a lockdown state where the user cannot go back to the app since there are no back buttons and the address from the a-tag is opened.

Is this possible? I know about the UIWebView (or such) that can be used in compiled apps, but it doesn't help here, naturally.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.google.com"]];
```

Comment: probably use this in shouldStartLoadWithRequest method, openURL, then return NO, because I believe question is how open Safari when user clicks "a href", so request will start, we need to cancel it and OpenUrl.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious, but how do I implement this with HTML/JS? Is this something Cordova can handle, a system call that needs compiled binaries or what?